# Web project design, in what order to build things?

Tags: python, django

I need help coming up with a good order to build a web application in. I am building it in django. Its a web app thats going to have alot of things like voting, liking, creating lists, commenting etc. So to keep my options open in  the future for simplicity of building a multi-platform webapp, I was thinking building the website "API up".

Not sure if I am using the right terms, but essentially I want to build all the function parts using REST e.g. to like a comment would be url.com/api/like/commentID/user/Pass where user pass is optional since it can use a web session if it has one. Once I build the functions (like, comment, etc) I plan on building views and templates on top of the api (e.g the like button is a simple href to the api like function).

I think this is kinda different from my typical way in the sense that I'd usually have to have multiple methods one for an api type of thing, and one for view/templates forms and such.

Essentially I am asking, would building an website on top of your API be a good idea?

Comment: Never pass a password in the URL.

Comment: Yes.  What more do you want to know about your approach?  This is not a "technical" question and probably belongs on Programmers.StackExchange.Com

Comment: It's a good plan in general. However, I don't believe it's smart to reinvent the wheel in this area. django-tastypie (https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie) is an excellent drop-in API app, that will server your project well.

Comment: Eating your own dog food is always a good idea.  However, there are better ideas (well, at least, with a higher priority), such as making sure you get users, and getting visibility.  It's no use providing an API if you don't establish enough users to keep your site alive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Keep it simple and stupid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Start by writing a **simple list of [user stories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story)** - don't over-design your project. Group them by app. Try to divide your project in many apps but not too many.

> Controlling complexity is the essence of computer programming. — [Brian Kernigan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan)

Start your project with [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) or something like that. So that you get all the user management/settings/registration/etc/etc ... out of the box. **You can now start focusing on what makes your website different**.

> Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it. — [Brian W. Kernighan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan) and [P. J. Plauger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P._J._Plauger) in [The Elements of Programming Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Programming_Style).

Code the first version of the first app, that should include **a few models**, urls, views, templates and staticfiles.

> There are two ways of constructing a software design: One way is to make it so simple that there are obviously no deficiencies and the other way is to **make it so complicated that there are no obvious deficiencies**. — [C.A.R. Hoare, The 1980 ACM Turing Award Lecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C.A.R._Hoare)

**Postpone features which doesn't fit into the standard Django way of coding** (e.g. requires hacks, code bloat, etc ..). Rely on external apps as much as possible, improve them rather than re-inventing the wheel.

> Life is too short to run proprietary software. — [Bdale Garbee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bdale_Garbee)

Code the other apps, again try to keep them simple if something is too complex then postpone it.

> The cheapest, fastest, and most reliable components are those that aren't there — [Gordon Bell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_Bell)

You should then **have a first working version of your project**. Time has gone by while you did that. Depending on the amount of time left, **decide which of the features you postponed are most important** for the first release.

> The computing scientist's main challenge is not to get confused by the complexities of his own making." — [E. W. Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._W._Dijkstra)

**Do the first release**, at least private, your project should be in production and you should have **succeeded in deadlines** by now. The code should be elegant and the user stories implemented somehow with simplicity in the code. Set up a **rolling release** system - that is make a script that can push from test to production.

> And folks, let's be honest. Sturgeon was an optimist. **Way more than 90% of code is crap**." — [Al viro](http://heretic.net-ronin.org/~ramune/humor/viro/)

You're now **ready to work on the more complex stuff**. But don't forget: **your website's usage (users and business model) should now be able to dictate the priorities**. You should have a **sane project** that evolves by itself now.

> It's a curious thing about our industry: not only do we not learn from our mistakes, we also don't learn from our successes." — Keith Braithwaite